# If I buy a Renfe ticket online, in what form do I get the actual ticket?

Tags: trains, tickets, spain

I will be traveling to Spain, and noticed that I can get a train ticket at a discount if I buy online now. I started filling the form, and they wanted to know lots of data, including an ID number(!) and my full address, even though I chose to buy without a registration.

This made me stop and think. Maybe they need my address so they can send me my ticket per snail mail? This would be unfortunate, as I will have left long before a letter from Spain arrives. But until a few years ago, this was the way I had to buy my online tickets in Germany - order them and they came in an envelope - so who knows, maybe the Spanish railway still hasn't changed to electronically delivered tickets?

I don't speak Spanish, so if the delivery method is explained somewhere on the site, I can't find it. Does anybody know if I can buy the ticket online and print it right away?

Comment: I don't know about RENFE, but often when booking advanced purchase train tickets there's a choice between print at home (with ID requirements) and posted tickets. Did you manage to get the booking site into English? And either way, what did it say about delivery options? (Screenshot could help)

Comment: If you are able to make a booking with RENFE page, you can do what you want ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did the same last year, I just printed the ticket page and took it along to Spain. No snail mail involved.

Answer (score 4):

I've found the same question [here](http://www.barcelona-tourist-guide.com/en/faq/transport/train/how-to-use-renfe-train-tickets-purchased-online.html). In sum:

> you can walk directly on the train with these [printed] tickets you do
>   not have to pick up any other tickets from the station

Also:

> If you did not have a printer at home then RENFE have Automatic
>   Check-In Booths at Barcelona Sants

Change "Barcelona Sants" for almost any big station name (Madrid, Valencia, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Those details you need to provide are irrelevant to the ticket, probably just insurance/statistical data. Tickets are generated immediately after checkout, and you get to choose whether download them as PDFs, Passbook/Passwallet (For your smartphone), or as a code sent through SMS (Or all of the above).

You will receive the printable PDF through e-mail too, but you can also print them in kiosks located on main stations and Madrid airport (Terminal 4 next to the subway kiosks)

Comment: Actually, RENFE might ask to see ID when boarding the train and check it against the supplied details. http://www.renfe.com/viajeros/info/billeteidentificativo.html

Comment: Yes, although it's not commonly enforced as far as I've seen/experienced